# GET working fine where POST in not working XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, xmlhttprequest

My GET request is working fine and responding as xml.
https://mydomain.com/mypage.php?id=123&nm=ak_dhara
Note: our php page is on https.

But POST is not working.

```
xhttp.open("POST"," https://mydomain.com/mypage.php",true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/xhtml+xml");
xhttp.send("id=123&nm=ak_dhara");
```

Any Suggestion ?

Comment: Is your PHP page reading parameters sent in POST ?

Comment: Can you provide more information from logcat?

Comment: Yes All I fixed this issue.<br>
xhttp_bookaroom_request.open("POST","https://mydomain.com/mypage.php
",true);<br>
    xhttp_bookaroom_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");<br>
                xhttp_bookaroom_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", fileAPI.length);<br>
    xhttp_bookaroom_request.send(fileAPI);
<br>

Comment: Hi but the above mentioend solution is not working with android using phonegap. Any idea

Answer (score 1):

`xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/xhtml+xml")` is wrong. If you want to ask for XHTML content, then the right request header name is `Accept`. If you want to identify the type of content that you're sending, then you're sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. A server that respects the headers will try to read the data that you sent, `id=123&nm=ak_dhara`, as a special kind of request encoded using the `application/xhtml+xml` format; and no PHP server knows how to do that. It might work in certain browsers because they know that's not a valid content type, and they ignore that header and send the correct value anyway.

By the way, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default one, so you don't have to set it explicitly.